# Transform JSON into CSV with Python issues

Tags: python, json, csv, indices

I am trying to convert a JSON file selectively into a CSV. Meaning that I want to iterate over the JSON.

The code to write my CSV looks like this:

```
f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "wb+"))
f.writerow(["id", "text", "polarity"])
for x in final:
    f.writerow([x["id"], 
                x["text"], 
                x["polarity"]])
```

Sadly, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I have already an idea what is the problem. I checked the type of my JSON after loading it. It is a dict so that should be fine.

When I print my dict:

```
print (final)
```

I get:

```
{u'data': [{u'polarity': 2, u'text': u'How deep is your love - Micheal Buble Ft Kelly Rowland ?', u'meta': {u'language': u'en'}, u'id': u'1'}, {u'polarity': 2, u'text': u'RT @TrueTeenQuotes: #SongsThatNeverGetOld Nelly ft. Kelly Rowland - Dilemma', u'meta': {u'language': u'en'}, u'id': u'2'}, {u'polarity': 2, u'text': u'RT @GOforCARL: Dilemma - Nelly Feat. Kelly Rowland #Ohh #SongsThatNeverGetOld', u'meta': {u'language': u'en'}, u'id': u'3'}, {u'polarity': 2, u'text': u'#NP Kelly Rowland Grown Woman', u'meta': {u'language': u'en'}, u'id': u'4'}, {u'polarity': 2, u'text': u"My friend just said 'kelly rowland is gettin it good... Most of her songs are sexual'", u'meta': {u'language': u'en'}, u'id': u'5'}, {u'polarity': 2, u'text': u'No. Kelly Rowland is the Black Barbie, idc', u'meta': {u'language': u'en'}, u'id': u'6'}, {u'polarity': 2, u'text': u'Nelly - Gone ft. Kelly Rowland http://t.co/tXjhCS05l0', u'meta': {u'language': u'en'}, u'id': u'7'}, {u'polarity': 2, u'text': u'Kisses Down Low by Kelly Rowland killer?\u2018?\u2018?\u2018 #NellyVille', u'meta': {u'language': u'en'}, u'id': u'8'}]}
```

Where every item seems to be in Unicode besides the value for 'polarity'. I have now 3 questions. 1. Should all items be in unicode or not? How can I change the format within the dict? Will that solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a dictionary in Python gives you the dict's keys as strings - thus `x` in your example above will contain just the string `"data"`

If you want to iterate over the dicts in the list value associated to the `u"data"` key of your  `final` dict, you have to write that in Python:

```
...
for x in final[u"data"]:
    f.writerow([x["id"], 
                x["text"], 
                x["polarity"]])
```

Comment: This is already bringing me a lot further. But I still get an "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2018' in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)" error. So I guess I have to recode the JSON somehow?!